# Making a decimal a whole number

Tags: python, numpy

I need to take a number like (0.25) and multiply by ten repeatedly until there are no values after the decimal point.

For example, if the number was `.25` then I would need to multiply by ten repeatedly:

`.25 * 10 * 10 = 25`

or if the number was `1.5`

`1.5 * 10 = 15`

What would be the best way to do this? A for loop?
I know I should do something like

```
number = .75
for i in range(0,10):
    number * 10**i = ???? (this is where I am stuck)
```

Comment: Is this an exercise in recursion?

Comment: This sounds like a headache waiting to happen when ordinary floating-point rounding causes your code to receive `0.30000000000000004` instead of `0.3` or something like that.

Comment: @user2357112 - I wonder if a correct answer might  include [`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html)?

Comment: Might be easier to just say if the next *x* decimal places are 0, call it good.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this

```
x=.25
while int(x) != x:
    x=x*10
```

Comment: What answer do you get for `x=.81`?

Comment: The following two-digit decimal (literals) will blow up: `0.07`, `0.14`, `0.23`, `0.28`, `0.46`, `0.47`, `0.53`, `0.56`, `0.57`, `0.59`, `0.81`, `0.83`, `0.92`, `0.94`

Comment: Yea those get a little funky, but that wasn't the issue in the original question. If Caroline amends it, I'll be happy to address it.

Answer (score 0):

If the input is always positive fraction (1 > x > 0), I would try this:

```
def fraction2int(b):
    return int('{}'.format(b).replace('0.', ''))
```

Comment: What's the point of `'{}'.format(x)` vs. `str(x)`? You could also probably handle other numbers if you just remove all `.`'s and `lstrip('0')`

Comment: `1.4e-19` is between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
x=.25
while x % 1.0 != 0:
    x=x*10
```

Comment: What answer do you get for `x=.81`?

Comment: @Robᵩ with  x =.81 the result is 81

Comment: Hmm. When I run your code with `x=.81`, I get this: `8100000000000001.0` Python3 demo: https://ideone.com/Mwl0KL  Python2 demo: https://ideone.com/E2T6xH

Comment: ok, i just tested it, as Nick T said some decimals blow up, i tested it first in my web browser console, sorry.

Comment: @Robᵩ can u explain why 81.0 % 1.0 in my python console is 0.0 but dont break my while loop?

Comment: Because `.81`, like most other numbers, is not precisely representable as a binary floating-point number. The literal `.81` is not precisely 81 hundredths., but evaluates to something closer to `0.81000000000000005329`.  Therefore `(.81 * 10) * 10` is not precisely 81, but something closer to `81.000000000000005329`.  For more information, see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: To see how this works out in your example, add `print('{0:.40f}'.format(x))` to your loop.